# In Debian 6, how to start a daemon as a different user?

Tags: debian, init-script, tor

I'm trying to start the Tor daemon as another user. When it installs, Tor automatically creates a new user "debian-tor", however, it does not run as this user, but rather as root.

In Debain 5 I removed Tor from start up with Update-rc.d, and added a new start up script that basically does `su debian-tor -c '/etc/init/tor $1'`. This worked great, but in Dabian 6 (using insserv instead of update-rc.d) it asked for **debiant-tor**'s password (in spite of running as root).

I'm at a loss here, my iptables will only work if Tor runs as a different user, and it's much safer not to run it as root. What can I do?

Comment: I can see in my rc.d that the debian daemon starter can accept users  `grep -nire start-stop-daemon /etc/init.d/ /etc/init.d/xpilot-ng-server:35: start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $USER --background \`

Answer (score 1):

Services are usually meant to run as root. However, you have 2 options:

1. You have some sort of script that launches the service as that user. There are a few ways to accomplish this. You could do the following:

   ```
   sudo -u debian-tor /etc/init.d/service
   ```

   and then add debian-tor to the sudoer's file for this command
2. You can use the stop-start-daemon with the --chuid option.

Comment: This is a partial solution. It seems that `init.d/tor` runs as root and then drops to debian-tor. It does open ports with the uid of root, which made the iptables rules not function properly. I tried checking with `ps` and `lsof`, all the relevant ports seemed to belong to `debian-tor`, so I really don't understand what could be causing this. Is there any other thing I can check or change?

Comment: How to make this service start automatically? The presence in `rc0.d/` seems not enough!